# Protocol doesn't support the "===" operator?

Tags: swift

It seems that `protocol` doesn't support the `===` operator, while `class` does.

```
protocol P {
}

class A : P {
}

var a1 = A()
var a2 = A()
var p1:P = a1
var p2:P = a2

a1 === a2    // true
p1 === p2    // error: Type 'P' does not conform to protocol 'AnyObject'
```

I think it could probably caused by the fact that the concrete type that conforms to the protocol could also be a value type (like `struct`) which doesn't support the `===` operator.
I'm just wondering that if I'm sure the real type is a class, how can I compare the references of them, like the `p1` and `p2` here?

Comment: If you are sure, you have to cast them to `A` before you compare? BTW, I have no idea about `swift`.

Comment: you can annotate the protocol can only be implemented by class, but I can't remember the syntax...

Comment: In fact, casting to `AnyObject` made sense to me too.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

First let's look at the definition of the `===` operator. It isn't just a test of equality between the value of two instances, but it checks to see if two variables point to the *exact same instance* of an object ([see "Identity Operators" here](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_135)).

So your example code isn't quite right:

```
var a1 = A()
var a2 = A()
var a3 = a2
a1 === a2     // actually false, a1 and a2 were instantiated separately
a2 === a3     // true, because they are the same instance
```

Only classes can be compared in this way, because everything that isn't a class in Swift is value-typed*, and two value-typed variables can't possibly be pointing to the same instance.

Therefore, if you try to compare a regular protocol with `===`, Swift doesn't have enough information to use the operator. The instances you're comparing (`p1` and `p2`) could be class instances or they could be struct instances, and at *compile-time* Swift can't tell if it's okay.

If you want to be able to use a protocol as a type in this way *and* compare with `===`, you'll need to declare a *class-only protocol* by using `class` as the first item in your protocol's inheritance list, like this:

```
protocol P : class {
}

class A : P {
}
```

Now you can do what you were attempting, without the compiler error:

```
var p1:P = a1
var p2:P = a2
var p3:P = a3
p1 === p2    // false
p2 === p3    // true
```

---

*Semantically, anyway. Swift does a lot of behind-the-scenes reference-typing, but enforces this value-typed behavior, so for the purposes of this discussion just go with `struct` and `enum` being truly value-typed.

Comment: Nice, this is exactly what I want. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you, Nate! 
Brilliant explanation! And it's still valid with Swift 3. :)
This "class-only protocol" saved my day - totally forgot about it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Saved my day!

Comment: Very clear explanation! The fix worked and I typed it while knowing what I was doing. Thank you 

Answer (score 1):

### **Equality between protocols**

Drop this in playground and your on your way.

```
protocol IPositional:class{}
class A:IPositional{}
class B:IPositional{}
let a:IPositional = A()
let b:IPositional = B()
let c:IPositional = a
a === b //false
a === c //true
```

Answer (score 0):

Conform the protocol to either `class` or `AnyObject`
This means that **only classes** will be able to conform to that protocol, not struct.

For example, from:

```
protocol P {
}
```

to (*Swift 4 version*)

```
protocol P : AnyObject {
}
```

or (*Swift 3 version*)

```
protocol P : class {
}
```